# Error using osql.exe (Sql Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server-2005, file, osql

I use sql server 2005 enterprise, windows server 2003.

I try execute osql.exe command, for execute sql file in my server DESSQL:

```
osql.exe -E -n-1 -i"CarpetaUno\TextFile1.sql"
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server DESSQL, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'n'
```

UPDATE:

I try this too,

```
osql.exe -E -i"CarpetaUno\TextFile1.sql"

1> 2> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server DESSQL, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'n'
```

Finally, I use SQLCMD command:

SQLCMD -E -b -i"CarpetaUno\TextFile1.sql"

But not works using osql command !!

I test:

1.) using -S ServerName option,

2.) using absolute path: osql.exe -E --i C:\CarpetaUno\TextFile1.sql

3.) TextFile1.sql contents, is OK, I test using SSMS

```
CREATE DATABASE PRUEBA;

DROP DATABASE PRUEBA;
```

but I get the same error, in all tests.

Can it fails if I use utf-8 encoding in file ???

any solutions?

Comment: You sure it's not a problem with your TextFile1.sql, can you run the file manually?

Comment: can we see line 1 of the file TextFile1.sql

Comment: TextFile1.sql contents: CREATE DATABASE PRUEBA;

Comment: Have you tried a space between -i and the SQL file, like this:

osql.exe -E -i "CarpetaUno\TextFile1.sql"

Comment: also add -e and double check the input SQL is what you expect

Comment: Have you tried sqlcmd, osql is deprecated.

Comment: Could you provide the whole TextFile1.sql by any chance? (or an edited version; names changed to protect the innocent!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're barking up the wrong tree..

Error 102 is incorrect SQL syntax, more than likely from the source SQL file.

**Update**
I think you've answered your own question..
OSQL accepts ANSI and Unicode encoded files, BUT I tried opening my file with notepad++ changed the encoding to UTF-8 and I got similar errors.

A quick google gave me [this](http://kiribao.blogspot.com/2008/03/osql-and-input-file-encodings.html) and [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/10/14/osql-exe-and-unicode-files-how-to-save-your-sql-scripts-with-encoding.aspx) with a little bit more information.

### The bottom line is: Use SQLCMD.exe

Comment: TextFile1.sql contents, is OK, I test using SSMS. Can it fails if I use utf-8 encoding in file ??

Comment: Try running it using sqlcmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

The `-n` option removes the `1> 2> ...` line number prompts and afaik there are no other flags that go along with it so remove the `-1`.

Comment: I try this too, osql.exe -E -i"CarpetaUno\TextFile1.sql" and fails same.

Comment: Then it sounds like a prob with the SQL inside "CarpetaUno\TextFile1.sql"

Comment: Can it fails if I use utf-8 encoding in file ??

Comment: Yes, it wont work with utf-8, use ucs2 (little endn.) or utf16 (or ansi), alternatively try the sqlcmd.exe utility